# while find Max of two pandas element of current and previous getting error 'list' object has no attribute 'max'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, max

Sadly I get this error when I try to do `max()` tried with multiple `[] ()` combination and the error keeps on coming .

Looks like this is minor issue and easily solvable. Before posting it here referred some of the existing posts still could not figure out the way.

Any help much appreciated. The code fails after if is evaluated (last line)

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if(df[source].iat[i] > df[trail].iat[i - 1]) and (df[source].iat[i-1] > df[trail].iat[i-1]):
            df[trail].iat[i] = [df[trail].iat[i-1],df[source].iat[i]- df['nLoss'].iat[i]].max()
```

error :'list' object has no attribute 'max'

Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Try change `[df[trail].iat[i-1],df[source].iat[i]- df['nLoss'].iat[i]].max()` to `max([df[trail].iat[i-1],df[source].iat[i]- df['nLoss'].iat[i]])`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` and `np.ndarrays` objects have `.max()` method, [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) do not. Consider @jezrael's comment or use a different container.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you ,this works; when to use max(df..) and df[].max() it is bit not clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function working with iterables in python:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if(df[source].iat[i] > df[trail].iat[i - 1]) and (df[source].iat[i-1] > df[trail].iat[i-1]):
            df[trail].iat[i] = max([df[trail].iat[i-1],df[source].iat[i]- df['nLoss'].iat[i]])
```